# Hidden gesture to scroll to top of SMS list, or glitch?

Tags: sms

I've noticed that sometimes my phone (Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 4.3) jumps to the top of a SMS list. This is a useful feature that I'd like to reproduce but I never found a gesture or option for that.

According to [these answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39230/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-a-list), there is no predefined gesture on Android and the solution is to install an app on a rooted device. However, a couple of times it worked as such by tapping twice on the top edge of the phone; I don't know if it's an undocumented feature and is supposed to work this way, or it's a glitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running the stock version of Android 4.3 on your S3, this is actually a feature provided by Samsung's TouchWiz. You can find the toggle for it in `Settings > System > Motion`. You can find documentation for it on [Samsung's support section](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/skp/faq/1060822). It says:

> **Double tap to top**: When viewing a long list, like your contacts list, or scrolling through a website, tap the top of your device twice to be taken back to the top of the list or page.
>
> [image: 240]

Comment: I edited the answer and quoted the relevant part because I've never used a Samsung device, so I had trouble understanding (only from text) how this gesture works. I hope that's OK with you!

Comment: @Firelord - no worries, it's much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks. I've activated the option. It doesn't seem to work, but this is a different problem. +1 and marking this answer as accepted.