# Volume Button To Scroll Up Android

Tags: applications, root-access, 7.0-nougat

So there is probably one feature I miss sincerely and that is being able to hit the title bar on the iPhone to essentially trigger the "Home key."  Is there a way to assign this to one of the volume switchers or maybe add a fourth button to the bar at the bottom or even double tap the home button maybe.  I use it a lot and want it to be easily accessible.  [I opened an xda question.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/themes/home-key-android-t3604421)  [This question is almost a duplicate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39230/how-do-i-scroll-to-the-top-of-a-list).

Comment: Provided your device is rooted and a compatible Xposed Framework is installed, use GravityBox [LP] module. It can  add things in Navigation bar. Otherwise, try Xposed Additions module. It can assign a custom action to any hardware key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the best solution I have come up with out a root.  Basically install and pay for the application called [Volkey scroll](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tafayor.vkscroll).

Then set the following settings.

[image]

[image]

1. Uncheck "Enable persistent notification."
2. Enable Automatic Start.
3. Set speed of scrolling to 100/100.
4. Selected action leap.
5. Stop scrolling after a timeout 500 seconds
6. Page size disable.
7. Continuous pages checked
8. The delay between pages 1

Now you only have to hold down the button until it stops at the top or bottom.  Sometimes you have to press it more then once to get this to work for example in Google Photos not sure why.  Now to adjust the volume you have to disable the app temporarily which is annoying or add it to the menu bar which isn't to bad.

---

So basically here is the deal someone created a plugin for this in older versions of android [here](https://github.com/MohammadAG/Xposed-StatusBar-Scroll-To-Top).  I can't confirm or deny if this works.  [Here is another app](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/add-tap-scroll-functionality-android-quickly-jump-top-bottom-any-page-0161838/) and [a reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3csmy5/android_needs_a_systemwide_scrolltotop_feature/).

For chrome you can set you javascript home bookmark to do the following.  `javascript:window.scrollTo(0,0)` which fixes Chrome.

[This is volume scroll application and it appears to essentially emulating scrolling using accessibility and displaying it on screen.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tafayor.autoscroll2)